# .Net WebBrowser control doesn't load all images in HTML page under Win7 and IE 11

Tags: html, winforms, windows-7, webbrowser-control

I have been using a WebBrowser control in a Windows Form application (.Net 2.0) for years and it always worked fine under XP. The only thing this WebBrowser is used for is to open one big locally stored HTML file, with lots of PNG pictures (total size about 1MB).

However, the application has a problem when running under Windows 7 with IE 11: It doesn't load all the images anymore. Several of the images that are further down the page don't show up immediately, but after pressing F5 (refresh) they do show up. (And as said under XP there is no problem).

What could cause this and how can I solve it?

EDIT: I discovered that the problem only occurs when the page is opened from the top, not when opened with an anchor.

Comment: Does the same thing happen when you use IE from the same machine that has the problem? Because the WebBrowser control _is_ IE. Besides that, I wonder if you are ignoring exceptions or other errors?

Comment: @JohnSaunders No, when i just open the page in IE it works fine. I have IE 11 installed on this Win7 machine but (oddly?) the UserAgent of the WebBrowser is reported as Mozilla/4.0 (compatible ;MSIE 7.0, etc.) which it also is under my XP machine which has IE 8 installed

Comment: @JohnSaunders No exceptions occuring when the WebBrowser.Url is set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that I just had to add the correct doctype declaration, for plain old HTML in this case:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
```

This solved the problem.

See http://www.w3.org/wiki/Choosing_the_right_doctype_for_your_HTML_documents to learn more.